# What rail can I use to build a tilt-shift medium format camera?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, camera-modification

I am building a medium format camera that uses 120 film and contains several digital and video parts. Final image format is 6x45 cm.
I would like to mount the lens on a rail that allows to tilt and shift and lets me focus from macro to infinity, and whose mounts I would adapt to the body and lens I plan to use.
A lot of commercial bellows that exist (Canon Auto Bellows, etc) are a good start but do not allow tilt/shift.

***What is a good rail with bellows that would allow me to build the camera this way?***

Comment: Would adapting a large format be overkill (size wise) for what you had in mind?

Comment: It might be a little too large/heavy/expensive, which ones did you have in mind? I also wonder how bad the vignetting/black edges would be with a 35mm bellow system

Comment: I'm not sure about the 35 bellows. Was just looking over at my Cambo and thinkin'...that might work...But, though it is relatively cheap, it isn't small.

Comment: What is the model of the Cambo? I just searched Cambo bellows and everything was $300 and up (which is more than $20 canon 35mm ones)

Comment: You know, I'm not terribly sure. Bought it used locally. But, the rail looks similar to this: https://www.ebay.com/itm/Cambo-4x5-Monorail-View-Camera-Body-av/223273209120?hash=item33fc1ecd20:g:JUEAAOSwMKFcCUBn:sc:USPSPriority!97008!US!-1

Comment: That's a good suggestion! I'll wait to see others. I also found this system (last photo) - but this looks like something I could even make myself... https://www.cambo.com/en/news/new-interfaces-for-mirrorless-full-frame/

Comment: That looks pretty cool!

Answer (score 2):

There are medium format cameras with substantial movements such as the Horseman 9xx series, VH, and VHR. Linhoff has made similar models. The “Baby Graflex’s” are also well known. There are many lesser known brands. Collectively these are often referred to as “medium format press cameras” though that also can refer to cameras with few or no movements.

More broadly, 4x5 cameras with graflok backs can accept roll film adapters. These are widely available in the used market.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up deciding to mount the camera on an adjustable camera platform [such as this one](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/899257-REG/Dot_Line_dl_0322_Adjustable_Camera_Platforms_6.html).
It is cheap, precise and convenient since you can fasten the position.

Comment: How does that address your desire for tilt and shift?

Comment: @AlaskaMan it doesn’t! There was no activity on this question so I thought to accept what solution I have in mind now. I changed it so answers are still open!